# Create constraint for control insert in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, constraints

There are two tables - orders and a list of services. In the first there is a bool field that the order is approved, if it is true then you can’t insert / delete values in the second table. With the UPDATE of the first table and the DELETE of the second, it is clear.

INSERT make as

```
INSERT INTO b (a_id, b_value)
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1, 'AA1-BB1'),(1, 'AA1-BB2'),(1, 'AA1-BB3')) va
    WHERE (SELECT NOT confirm FROM a WHERE a_id = 2);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7b0086967c1c38b0c80ca5624ebe92e9

How to forbid to insert without triggers and stored procedures? Is it possible to compose somehow complex constraint or a foreign key for checking conditions at the DBMS level?

Comment: ' without triggers and stored procedures'. Sadly that is how you would fix these type of issues.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent version of Postgres supports generated columns.  So, you can do:

```
alter table b add  confirm boolean generated always as (false) stored;
```

Then create a unique key in `a`:

```
 alter table a add constraint unq_a_confirm_id unique (confirm, id);
```

And finally the foreign key relationship:

```
alter table b add constraint fk_b_a_id_confirm
    foreign key (confirm, a_id) references a(confirm, id);
```

Now, only `confirmed = false` ids can be used.  Note that this will prevent updates to `a` that would invalidate the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Thank you! I like your decision. Unfortunately, I use three states. True - confirmed, false - edited, null - formed.

Comment: @yrichs . . . I don't see that that matters.  Postgres allows multiple `NULL` values in a unique index.

Comment: I did not understand how to use your method
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4196ae9a10868dbe717900db7de76f04

Comment: @yrichs . . . The column names were off.  Here is an example that does what you want:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2e005ec6dc88c5070354df5ec4145dce.

Comment: How set confirm=true in table a?
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=01e81168d200815c0c20d70167101d96

Comment: @yrichs . . . You have to be sure that no "b"s refer to it.